# Error listing files with Google Drive API (PHP)

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I'm trying to list files in Google Drive using Google's PHP API (https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/quickstart/php).

I've managed to obtain a scoped access token, but the sample code Google provides for listing files (https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list#response) is returning an error.

Here is my code:

```
$client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setAuthConfigFile('/usr/share/nginx/google.json');
    $client->setAccessToken($a4e->user->google_token); // access token scoped for DRIVE_READONLY
    $drive_service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);

    $files=retrieveAllFiles($drive_service);
    var_dump($files);

    function retrieveAllFiles($service) {
      $result = array();
      $pageToken = NULL;

      do {
        try {
          $parameters = array();
          if ($pageToken) {
            $parameters['pageToken'] = $pageToken;
          }
          $files = $service->files->listFiles($parameters);

          $result = array_merge($result, $files->getItems());
          $pageToken = $files->getNextPageToken();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
          print "An error occurred: " . $e->getMessage();
          $pageToken = NULL;
        }
      } while ($pageToken);
      return $result;
    }
```

This returns the following error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method
>   Google_Service_Drive_FileList::getItems() in
>   /usr/share/nginx/html/tools/google/index.php on line 30

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are using Drive API V3 and trying to invoke a method of version V2 in V3 . Clearly look in the documentation , the Drive API V2 returns response in following format `{
  "kind": "drive#fileList",
  "etag": etag,
  "selfLink": string,
  "nextPageToken": string,
  "nextLink": string,
  "items": [
    files Resource
  ]
}`
So you can do a `$files->getItems()` in V2 . But the Drive API V3 return response for listing in following format `{
  "kind": "drive#fileList",
  "nextPageToken": string,
  "files": [
    files Resource
  ]
}`
So , you may need to do a `$files->getFiles()`. Give it a try !! I hope this will work . For your reference 
[Drive API V3 Listing Response](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/list#response)
[Drive API V2 Listing Response](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list#response)
. Let me know if issue is resolved .

Comment: Thank you! This did the trick. I didn't realize I was trying to use code from the wrong version of the API - I'll be more careful next time. Thanks for helping me fix this issue!